# Question in Differential Equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to this particular problem for several hours now. I have to find the general solution to:
$y^{(6)}+y=0$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The solutions of $r^6=-1$ are $e^{i\pi/6}$, $e^{2i\pi/6}$, $e^{3\pi i/6}$, and  $e^{-i\pi/6}$, $e^{2i\pi/6}$, $e^{3\pi i/6}$. Recall that $e^{it}$ and $e^{-it}$ are linear combinations of $e^{it}$ and $e^{-it}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is known from the theory of linear ODE with constant coefficients that the general solution is a linear combination of the functions $x \mapsto e^{\lambda_j x}$, where $j=1,\ldots,6$ and $\lambda_j^6+1=0$.

Comment: That only gave me two. How do I get the remaining four?

Comment: What two? Hint: use complex numbers.